# 英語が残っている：通報ダイアログに「rude or abusive」

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳

通報を行う際の理由を尋ねるダイアログに英語が残っていました。

[image: dialogue]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ストリングはこちらになります:

https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ja/translate/#ja/english/48712460?q=rude%20or%20abusive

とりあえず「失礼又は暴言」として翻訳しましたが、適用は次回のビルドになります。

Comment: ちなみにビルドってどのくらいの頻度で行われているのでしょうか？

Comment: @holywise 平日なら、毎日何回しますが、開発者が主に欧米にいるため、日本の昼間にあまりしないです。